$\int_1\dots\int_n\tan^{-1}(x)dx_{1\dots}dx_n$ (Integrating $\arctan$ an Arbitrary Amount of Times)
$$\int_1\dots\int_n\tan^{-1}(x)dx_{1\dots}dx_n$$
I have been trying to solve the above integral, for no reason other than my enjoyment. I am not sure if a closed-form solution exist, or if I am even on track. I have shared my attempt thus far and am looking for a nudge in the right direction.
To begin I used Cauchy's formula for repeated integration:
$$f^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_a^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}\tan^{-1}(t)dt$$
From here I integrated by parts and then rewrote the numerator using the Binomial Expansion:
$$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$(x-t)^n=n!x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}t^k$$
$$x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\int_0^x\frac{t^k}{1+t^2}dt$$
Now, factoring the denominator into $(1+it)(1-it)$ and using PFD
$$x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\int_0^x\left( \frac{t^k}{1+it}+\frac{t^k}{1-it} \right)dt$$
I did long division with each fraction $k$ times and then distributed and simplified:
$$\frac{x^n}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\int_0^x\left( (-1)^k\frac{1}{i^k}\frac{1}{1+it}+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{i^j}t^{k-j}+\frac{1}{1-it}-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{i^j}t^{k-j} \right)dt$$
$$\frac{x^n}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\left( \frac{(-1)^k}{i^k}\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+it}dt+\frac{1}{i^k}\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-it}dt+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1-(-1)^j}{i^j}\int_0^xt^{k-j}dt \right)$$
After integrating I'm left with:
$$\frac{x^n}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\left( \frac{(-1)^k}{i^{k+1}}\ln(1+ix)-\frac{1}{i^{k+1}}\ln(1-ix)+\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1-(-1)^j}{i^j(k-j+1)}x^{k-j+1} \right)$$
Here I am not sure how to proceed. I had the idea of using Euler's formula to separate the real and imaginary parts of the natural logs, but I don't know what I would do from there.

The argument of inverse tangent is $x$, but the dummy variables of integration have subscripts $(x_1, …, x_n)$. How are the two related? It’s not possible to answer your question without clarifying this.

@RiversMcForge, I think he was seeking a family of functions $\mathcal {f}{n} \left( x \right)$ such that $\mathcal {f}{n}^{\left( n \right)} \left( x \right) = \arctan \left( x \right)$.

You can also calculate the $n$th derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and set $n\to -n$

For $\left| x \right| \le 1$,
$$\begin{align} \mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) & = \frac {1}{n!} \int_{0}^{x} \frac {{\left( x - t \right)}^{n}}{1 + {t}^{2}} \text {d} t \\ & = \frac {1}{n!} \int_{0}^{x} {\left( x - t \right)}^{n} \sum_{k \ge 0} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} {t}^{2 k} \text {d} t \\ & = \frac {1}{n!} \sum_{k \ge 0} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} \int_{0}^{x} {t}^{2 k} {\left( x - t \right)}^{n} \text {d} t \\ & = \frac {1}{n!} \sum_{k \ge 0} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} {x}^{n + 2 k + 1} \int_{0}^{1} {t}^{2 k} {\left( 1 - t \right)}^{n} \text {d} t = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} \left( 2 k \right)!}{\left( n + 2 k + 1 \right)!} {x}^{n + 2 k + 1}. \end{align}$$
Above, we have used the formula for infinite geometric series and the formula for the beta integral, both of which the reader should be familiar with.
A special case is when $n \mapsto 2 n - 1$:
$$\mathcal {f}_{2 n - 1} \left( x \right) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{k} \left( 2 k \right)!}{\left( 2 n + 2 k \right)!} {x}^{2 n + 2 k}.$$
Let's introduce the rising factorial:
$$\begin{align} \frac {\left( 2 n + 2 k \right)!}{\left( 2 n \right)!} & = {\left( 2 n + 1 \right)}_{2 k} \\ & = {2}^{k} \, {\left( n + 1 \right)}_{k} \cdot {2}^{k} \, {\left( n + 1 / 2 \right)}_{k}. \end{align}$$
Using this result, we show
$$\frac {\left( 2 k \right)!}{\left( 2 n + 2 k \right)!} = \frac {1}{\left( 2 n \right)!} \cdot \frac {{\left( 1 \right)}_{k} {\left( 1 / 2 \right)}_{k}}{{\left( n + 1 \right)}_{k} {\left( n + 1 / 2 \right)}_{k}}.$$
Finally, plugging this back, we derive
$$\boxed {\mathcal {f}_{2 n - 1} \left( x \right) = \frac {{x}^{2 n}}{\left( 2 n \right)!} \; {}_{3} \text {F}_{2} \left( 1, \, 1, \, \frac {1}{2}; \, n + 1, \, n + \frac {1}{2}; \, - {x}^{2} \right).}$$

Let's assume, as @Simon suggested, that you are seeking a family of functions $F_n(x)$, where $n \in \Bbb{N_0} := \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, ... \}$, such that $F_0(x) = \arctan(x)$ and for all $n \in \Bbb{N_1} = \{ 1, 2, 3, ... \}$, $$F_n'(x) = F_{n-1}(x).$$ $F_1(x)$ is easy to calculate via the inverse function integral formula $$\int g^{-1}(x) dx = x g^{-1}(x) - G(g^{-1}(x)) + C,$$ where $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of the invertible function $g(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$ is its inverse. In this case, we have $g(x) = \tan(x)$, $g^{-1}(x) = \arctan(x)$, $G(x) = \ln|\tan(x)+\sec(x)|$, and $$G(g^{-1}(x)) = \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1}),$$ giving us
\begin{align*}
F_1(x) &= \int \arctan(x) dx \\ 
&= x \arctan(x) - \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2+1}) + C \\
&= x \arctan(x) - \operatorname{arsinh}(x) + C, \\
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{arsinh}(x)$ represents the inverse hyperbolic sine. From there, we can use integration by parts and the inverse function formula for antiderivatives to find $F_2(x), F_3(x),$ and so on.

Would you be able to find an explicit formula with this method?
